# is P2P really serverless?

Tags: c#, wcf, p2p

I am following this guide here. [P2P](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms751502%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

One of the advantages I had thought P2P would bring is the fact that it is a serverless setup.
Now that I have this working I noticed that you do need a resolver to keep track of who is connected.

To me this is really does require a server as you need a resolver to make P2P work in the first place.

Ami missing something?

Comment: You need a server to find peers, but once you've got your list of peers, you no longer need the server (until you need to refresh your list). It isn't truly serverless though.

Comment: The resolver doesn't sound like a server to me, it seems to just contain a mapping of mesh ids to ip addresses; similar to what you would see in a routing table.

Comment: well you need STUN and TURN to do WebRTC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your definition of a server I suppose.  Using a P2P game for example most players will connect to a central point, be matched up and will then communicate between themselves with no involvement from the server.

This means the server doesn't have to host any data it simply has to coordinate those who do.  It keeps resources down (as each client only needs to connect once) and the infrastructure is often more robust.

Do you need a central application to coordinate peers?  Yes

Does that application need to stream content/data to each peer?  No